# Export features to excel after fit-transform of the TFIDFVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

Python Version: 3.7

Hi everyone:

I am using the tfidfVectorizer from the library scikit-learn as follow:

```
vec_body = TfidfVectorizer(**vectorizer_parameters)
X_train_features = vec_body.fit_transform(X_train)
```

`X_train` contains the email body. If I understood correctly, X_train_features is a sparse matrix. My objective is to create an excel report to validate which features or words per mail were identified after transformation with the following table:

| email_body | email features |
| --- | --- |
| this is an example | example |
| this is another example | another example |
| ... | ... |

The column "email_body" should have the email body for each mail I have in the X_train. The column "email_features" should have a string with all the features or words after the transformation (fit-transform) for each particular mail. In the vectorizer, I deleted all stop words and used lemmatization too. That is why I want to export the result to excel to validate which words were used in the transformation. I do not know how to achieve that when my result is a sparse matrix.

Please forgive me if I explained something incorrectly but I am very new with this library. Thank so much in advance for any advice or solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that with `tfidf.get_feature_names_out()` and `np.flatnonzero` to find nonzero indices for each row of the transformed space. Like this:

```py
X = tfidf.fit_transform(documents)
words = tfidf.get_feature_names_out()
features = [" ".join(words[np.flatnonzero(row)]) for row in X.todense()]
```

Here's a simple example based on the examples in the question:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

documents = [
    "this is an example",
    "this is another great example",
]

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words="english")

X = tfidf.fit_transform(documents)
words = tfidf.get_feature_names_out()
features = [" ".join(words[np.flatnonzero(row)]) for row in X.todense()]

print(pd.DataFrame({"email_body": documents, "email_features": features}))
```

Which produces the following. You should be able to call [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) on the dataframe if you want an Excel file.

```
                      email_body    email_features
0             this is an example           example
1  this is another great example     example great
```